# How to improve WOT score of a site?

Tags: security, blog

I don't understand why my site `Trustworthiness` and `Vendor Reliability` are considered bad by [WOT](http://www.mywot.com/en/scorecard/teamoff.org).

I do not have ADS, I never spammed my site around, I do not have links that point to untrusted sites. Is this an error? How can improve it and get back to green lights?

Comment: Did you read this: http://www.mywot.com/en/trustseal/tips ? You need people to rate your site to have trustworthiness in WOT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this has been voted up, I'll go along with what Lese states as a comment and add this:

http://www.mywot.com/en/trustseal/tips/manage-your-reputation

Maybe if you share links to your site we could check it out further. I put in my current and previous companies' URLs in the "my" section and both score in the 70's. When I do a check on the "How Trusted..." search here:

http://www.mywot.com/en/trustseal

I get a message saying it's not trusted.

I think a big part of this is the site has lower traffic numbers.

Comment: The link is in the question, just click WOT.